# Redux call component functions within a state change (reducer)?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I just started implementing Redux in my application and so far so good, but now I got to a state variable that has some side effects (? im guessing) within its setState function and I can't figure out how to implement that with redux. I have an idea, but doesn't seem to be the best option.

```
function App() {
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);

  const handlePause = () => {
    setPaused(oldPauseStatus => {
      !oldPauseStatus ? pauseVisualizationHandler() : resumeVisualizationHandler();
      
      return !oldPauseStatus;
    })
  }

  const pauseVisualizationhandler = () => {...somecode...};
  const resumeVisualizationhandler = () => {...somecode...};

  return (<button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={handlePause}>
              {paused ? `RESUME` : `PAUSE`}
          </button>)
}
```

Now the problem is obvious, it is the `pause` and `resume` handlers within the `setPaused`.

For action I have:

```
const setPaused = (paused) => {
  return paused
    ? {
        type: PAUSE,
        payload: { paused },
      }
    : {
        type: RESUME,
        payload: { paused },
      };
};
```

And for reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  started: false,
  paused: false,
};

const animationStateReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {       
    case PAUSE:
      return {
        ...state,
        paused: payload.paused,
      };
    case RESUME:
      return {
        ...state,
        paused: payload.paused,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And the whole thing implemented with Redux:

```
import { setPaused } from "./actions"

function App() {
  const { paused } = useSelector(state=>state.animationState);

  useEffect(() => {
     paused ? pauseVisualizationHandler() : 
              resumeVisualizationHandler();
  }, [paused])

  const handlePause = () => {
    setPaused(!paused)
  }

  const pauseVisualizationhandler = () => {...somecode...};
  const resumeVisualizationhandler = () => {...somecode...};

  return (<button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={handlePause}>
              {paused ? `RESUME` : `PAUSE`}
          </button>)
}
```

Now this is working just fine when I `dispatch(setPaused(trueOrFalse))`, however, I can't figure out where to put my `visualizationHandlers` now? The only thing that comes to mind is to use `useEffect` that will track when `paused` is changed, and do it there, but if I have multiple such states, wouldnt that pollute my component with lots of `useEffects`...? (And I do have 1 that is a bit more complex than this). What would be the correct approach here and is `useEffect` my only viable option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
function App() {
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);

  const handlePause = () => {
    setPaused((oldPauseStatus) => !oldPauseStatus);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (paused) {
      pauseVisualizationHandler();
    } else {
      resumeVisualizationHandler();
    }
  }, [paused]);

  return (
    <button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={handlePause}>
      {paused ? `RESUME` : `PAUSE`}
    </button>
  );
}
```

EDIT: MAYBE YOU DON'T NEED LOCAL STATE AT ALL

```
function App() {
  const handleMode = (type) => {
    if(type === 'PAUSE'){
      // do PAUSE function
    }
    if(type === 'RESUME'){
      // do RESUME function
    }
    if(type === 'FAST'){
      // do FAST function
    }
    if(type === 'SLOW'){
      // do SLOW function
    }
    dispatch({
      type,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={(e) => handleMode(`PAUSE`)}>
        {`PAUSE`}
      </button>
      <button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={(e) => handleMode(`RESUME`)}>
        {`RESUME`}
      </button>
      <button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={(e) => handleMode(`FAST`)}>
        {`FAST`}
      </button>
      <button id={"pausehandler"} onClick={(e) => handleMode(`SLOW`)}>
        {`SLOW`}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

and here is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  type: "play",
};

const animationStateReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case "PAUSE":
      return {
        ...state,
        type,
      };
    case "RESUME":
      return {
        ...state,
        type,
      };
    case "FAST":
      return {
        ...state,
        type,
      };
    case "SLOW":
      return {
        ...state,
        type,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes that is what I said, my question is how to do that with Redux without using useEffect, because that will lead to a huge amount of useEffects, because right now I can do it without useEffect within the setPaused function, and that functionality is lost with my current implementation and knowledge of Redux.

Comment: I saw your edit and that still misses the point, I need to be able to call functions within the component based on the state of a variable (namely the pause and resume handlers in that situation).

Comment: so just put an `if statement` for `type input` and call `whatever function` you like

Comment: The functions are inside the component, they are not in the reducer, I cant call them in the reducer, thats the point I am making. Unless I pass them down with the payload, but that would be a whole lot of drilling and coupling to get them to the reducer.

Comment: I know what you're point is , but I mean put an `if statement ` in the `handleMode` function. whyyyyyy can't you do this ???!!!! :)

Comment: Okay, sorry:) now I got your point `setPaused(prevState => !prevState ? pause() : resume(); return !prevState)`, is the same as `paused ? pause() : resume(); setPaused(!paused)`. Silly me. I have a few other more complex examples, but I will probably manage with this in hand.

Comment: It's ok, glad I finally got an approve from you :))). have a nice day